# Create input change Event in a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I am using react with typescript. I have a parent function that gets Input change event.

Parent component:

```
public onFormChange = (key: string) =>
  (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  .....
  }

public render(): React.ReactNode {
  return (
   ....
   <Child onChange={onFormChange(key)}>
   ...
  )
}
```

I have created object in Child component, that looks like to event:

```
public onChangeTitle = () => {

  this.props.onChange({target: {value: 'val'}});
}
```

However, it triggers `Maximum update depth exceeded` error

So, How I should create Event in the child function programmically? I can't change parent function. Please give examples in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead** ( because it is calling the function.)

```
<Child onChange={this.onFormChange(key)}>
```

**Use** (setting up a reference)

```
<Child onChange={this.onFormChange}>
```